# Euler's Geometry Puzzle

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, geometry

Today (or tomorrow, depending on your timezone, by the time of posting) is the birthday of the great mathematician and physicist [Leonhard Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler). To celebrate his birthday, this challenge is about one of his theorems in geometry.

For a triangle, we define its [incircle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Incircle.html) to be the largest circle inside the triangle and its [circumcircle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumcircle.html) to be the circle that passes through all of the traingle's vertices.

Consider a triangle in a plane, we plot the center of its incircle I (sometimes called [incenter](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Incenter.html)) and the center of its circumcircle O (sometimes called [circumcenter](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumcenter.html)). Let \$r\$ be the radius of the incircle, \$R\$ be the radius of circumcircle, \$d\$ be the distance between I and O. [Euler's theorem in geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem_in_geometry) states that \$d^2=R(R-2r)\$.

## The challenge

In the spirit of this theorem, your task, is for a triangle given by the lengths of its three sides, output \$d\$ (the distance between incenter I and circumcenter O described above).

- Your code needs to take only the length of the three sides of triangle and output \$d\$. Inputs and outputs can be in any reasonable format.
- The absolute error or relative error from your output and correct answer must be no greater than \$10^{-2}\$.
- It's guaranteed that the three side lengths are positive integers and can form a non-degenerate triangle.
- Standard loopholes are forbidden.

Since this is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code in bytes wins!

## Examples

In the samples, the outputs are rounded to 3 decimal places. You, however, are free to round them to more decimal places.

```
[a,b,c]       -> d
[2,3,4]       -> 1.265
[3,4,5]       -> 1.118
[3,5,7]       -> 3.055
[7,9,10]      -> 1.507
[8,8,8]       -> 0.000
[123,234,345] -> 309.109
```

List of sample inputs:

`[[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[3,5,7],[7,9,10],[8,8,8],[123,234,345]]`

Answer (score 13):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>80 74 66</s>  65 bytes

```javascript
(a,b,c)=>(s=a+b+c,(p=a*b*c/s)*p/4*(s/=2)/(s-a)/(s-b)/(s-c)-p)**.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc7NDoMgEATge59kFxep/MT2QI99D0BtbIyQYpq@PTXevJBJ5jLfYd7u63L4zGnjaxzGMtkCjjwFtA/I1jW@CQTJOuZZEBlZEppBFlaigMzd0f7ogDwhY60pIa45LmO7xBdMIEmRxnaLz/k3DqAQL2ewz2TqwFBfAz3dqbvWxI321EAnFUmlSenzlfIH)

#### How?

This is derived from:

- The semiperimeter \$s\$ of the triangle:

  $$s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$$
- The circumradius \$R\$ of the triangle:

  $$R=\frac{abc}{4\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}}$$
- The product of the inradius \$r\$ and the circumradius:

  $$rR=\frac{abc}{2(a+b+c)}=\frac{abc}{4s}$$
- Euler's theorem:

  $$d=\sqrt{R(R-2r)}=\sqrt{R^2-2rR}=\sqrt{R^2-\frac{abc}{2s}}$$

Comment: Clever... using the perimeter at first, and then halving it.

Comment: [62 bytes](https://tio.run/##fc7NDoIwDMDxu0/Sjm7IPoIe8Oh7bGUYDGFGiPHtJ5ETl6WHf5P@Dn36j1/4Pb5WOac@5qHL4CkQY3cDL4JgsaeGULH0WIPfGv4NklE2@1oxohDKZU7zkqaopvSAATQZsqjWdB@/sQeDeDqC7UyuDBy1JdDSlZpzSVxomxJotCFtLBl7fCX/AA "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: @newbie Nice! But I think I'll leave this one unchanged, since the shorter version has already been posted by Tim Pederick.

Answer (score 8):

## Python 3, 66 bytes

This formerly took advantage of the [new assignment expressions ("walrus operator")](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) introduced in Python 3.8. Thanks to commentors, I've taken that out, so it works on previous versions too!

```py
lambda a,b,c:((a*b*c/(b+c-a)/(a+c-b)/(a+b-c)-1)*a*b*c/(a+b+c))**.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/RioMwEEXf/Yp5nNgxTYypteCfLJQkprSgjZg87H69G9wFd8GZhyE5916481d6hrdaB@g/1tFMdjBgyJK7IZrSlu6M9uQqw85o8rXbtZVjlWTlryB/nBxjZcn1@ljCBJNJT3hNc1gSvKIbQ/RF8jHdnYk@Qg@IWJOihhFIXl80owL@DWKmpDcu5fWQa2ozV1zoI39LHUmxBWjRHgiulDdzwYUQB1zWimrVkGpyvBIdl6JjrHiEBdAQWAKX3f5z9i63fMNe8LZlmRj93h9/hATDH/Pix3sKYy99JWoCY@P@ZOs3)

It's based on the same calculations described in [Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203493/13959), but using the perimeter \$p\$ instead of the semiperimeter \$s\$:
$$
\begin{aligned}\\
p&=a+b+c\\
 &=2s
\end{aligned}\\
\therefore d=\sqrt{R^2-\frac{abc}{p}}\\
\text{and } R^2=\frac{\left(abc\right)^2}{p(p-2a)(p-2b)(p-2c)}
$$

The grand total savings of this rearrangement is... two bytes.

Factoring \$p\$ out and expanding the terms in the denominator means I don't have to store \$p\$, saving another three bytes. I also stored the product \$abc\$ in a variable \$m\$, which saved some bytes at first... but it could later be factored out, turning the brackets-and-walrus into a liability, not a savings! Here's the final formula:
\begin{aligned}
d&=\sqrt{\frac{\left(abc\right)^2}{p(p-2a)(p-2b)(p-2c)}-\frac{abc}{p}}\\
&=\sqrt{\left(\frac{abc}{(b+c-a)(a+c-b)(a+b-c)}-1\right)\frac{abc}{p}}
\end{aligned}

Comment: [70 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY/dasMwDIXv8xS6tFMl9U@y/EDeZFBsx6WFuDaxL7anz0xWyAaRLiTx6Rw44Ts9/Ev2Yd3m6XNblNOzAoUazUiIGydV6tLQ0l1JyMdFXwzNayVK9Z76PQ2t3DXQsqzb7b56B06lBzxd8GuCZzSLj7ZINqabUdFGmIAQIlBiQxF4LT5aigX8K0IyxXbnnPenvMUuc1mz9kzf4YCc7QYt604eesydOasZYyecC4lCNiibbC/ZUHM2UFrc/QpEIWgEk9X2K1iTU77gCDjuXipGe@Qnv48I8x/xapdb8svEbcUEgtLxOOn2Aw)

Comment: @dingledooper: Thanks! I'd just realised the same thing myself: storing \$m\$ meant that I could multiply by it instead of squaring, saving a byte.

Comment: Actually... [66 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY/BroMgEEX3fsUswY4WRGpt4p@8pBmQpk20GGHx3tf7iC5sE2cWF3Lm3uROf/Hp32rpoftZBhpNT0Bo0N4Y5Sa3@SZnZk62IH5mlNSsagrLC7k9T5bzPC/18pj9CCPFJ7zGyc8RXsEOPrgsuhDvloIL0AFjrEKFNUeQZXXRHDP4GsYSRb1yKa@HXGOTuCqFPvI32KIUa4AWzcHBFdMmLkohxAGXlcJK1ajqFK9EW0rRcp49/AyMEAyCTW73OzmbWr5hL3hbsygEt/dn2yFC/2Ge3XCPfuikK0SFQCbsX778Aw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @newbie And here I thought factoring out \$m\$ wouldn't save anything... I hadn't realised that it meant being able to drop a pair of parentheses. Thanks!

Comment: @dingledooper: *facepalm* Thanks. Done.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>23</s> <s>22</s> <s>21</s> <s>20</s> <s>15</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
PDIœÆPt/<*IO/t
```

-5 bytes porting [*@Neil*'s Charcoal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203505/52210), so make sure to upvote him!!
-1 byte thanks to *@Grimmy*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/wMXz6OTDbQEl@jZanv76Jf//RxvpGOuYxAIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/AJfKo5MPtwWU6NtoVfrrl/x3MdY7vElJQePwfk2lQ6t1/kdHG@kY65jE6kQDSR1TMG2qYw6kzXUsdQwNgAwLHSAE0oZGxjpGxiY6xiamsbEA).

**Explanation:**

```python
P              # Take the product of the (implicit) input-list
               #  [a,b,c] → abc
 D             # Duplicate it
  Iœ           # Get all permutations of the input-triplet
               #  [a,b,c] → [[a,b,c],[a,c,b],[b,a,c],[b,c,a],[c,a,b],[c,b,a]]
    Æ          # Reduce each by subtracting:
               #  → [a-b-c,a-c-b,b-a-c,b-c-a,c-a-b,c-b-a]
     P         # Take the product of that
               #  → (a-b-c)(a-c-b)(b-a-c)(b-c-a)(c-a-b)(c-b-a)
               #   → (a-b-c)²*(b-a-c)²*(c-a-b)²
      t        # Take the square-root
               #  → sqrt((a-b-c)²*(b-a-c)²*(c-a-b)²)
       /       # Divide the initially duplicated product by it
               #  → abc/(sqrt((a-b-c)²*(b-a-c)²*(c-a-b)²))
        <      # Decrease it by 1
               #  → abc/(sqrt((a-b-c)²*(b-a-c)²*(c-a-b)²))-1
         *     # Multiply it by the initial product
               #  → abc(abc/(sqrt((a-b-c)²*(b-a-c)²*(c-a-b)²))-1)
          IO/  # Divide it by the input-sum
               #  → abc(abc/(sqrt((a-b-c)²*(b-a-c)²*(c-a-b)²))-1)/(a+b+c)
             t # And take the square-root of that
               #  → sqrt(abc(abc/(sqrt((a-b-c)²*(b-a-c)²*(c-a-b)²))-1)/(a+b+c))
               # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Or as a single formula:

$$d=\sqrt{\frac{abc\left(\frac{abc}{\sqrt{(a-b-c)^2\times(b-a-c)^2\times(c-a-b)^2}}-1\right)}{a+b+c}}$$

Comment: My attempt to port the formula I came up with clocks in at 17 bytes, which is bad, since it's only 18 in Charcoal...

Comment: @Neil Nice approach! I got it down to [15 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/wMXT3/PQdt0AfRstT3/9kv//o410jHVMYgE) porting your answer. Was about to go eat dinner, so will update it afterwards. :)

Comment: Ah, right, I couldn't find `·` in `info.txt`, and trying to use `x` tied the stack into knots, preventing me from using `PD`. Nice!

Comment: @Neil You're not the first one who couldn't find `·`; I see answers overlooking it so many times for some reason.. I personally never really use the `info.txt` but use the [wiki Commands page](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands) instead (although it is lacking some new builtins every now and then..) Btw, using the `x` we could still end up at 15 bytes: [`PDIxsOαP/<*IO/t`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/wMWzotj/3MYAfRstT3/9kv//o410jHVMYgE). ;)

Comment: It doesn't help that one says `a * 2` and the other says `2 * a`...

Comment: @Neil Haha, ok, that indeed explains a lot.. You'll have to direct those complains to _Adnan_, since he made the `info.txt` file (and 05AB1E language).

Comment: `IOI·-P` => `IœÆPt` for -1 ([verify all](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/AJfKo5MPtwWU6NtoVfrrl/x3MdY7vElJQePwfk2lQ6t1/kdHG@kY65jE6kQDSR1TMG2qYw6kzXUsdQwNgAwLHSAE0oZGxjpGxiY6xiamsbEA))

Comment: @Grimmy Oh, nice! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>31</s> 18 bytes

```
Ｉ₂∕×⊖∕ΠθΠ⁻Σθ⊗θΠθΣθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYs7D8IgFIX/iuNtgoOlnRxlNWmsW9MB4SaS8AgX6N9HsWk803l8R70lqSBtrRMZn@EmU4Y5Fkn4CCGDMJvRCE/jMIFARejQZ9THMFHQRWWIHTsd/m58STAX92tFKC/7PcSu6U/FFnao6Vrrslx6zno@MD6M61rPm/0A) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a vector of doubles and outputs a double. Explanation:

$$ \begin{align}d
&=\sqrt{R(R-2r)}\\
&=\sqrt{R^2-2Rr}\\
&=\sqrt{\left(\frac{abc}{4\Delta}\right)^2-\frac{abc}{2s}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{(abc)^2}{16\Delta^2}-\frac{abc}{2s}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{(abc)^2}{2s(2s-2a)(2s-2b)(2s-2c)}-\frac{abc}{2s}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{abc}{2s}\left(\frac{abc}{(2s-2a)(2s-2b)(2s-2c)}-1\right)}\\
\end{align} $$

where \$ 2s=a+b+c \$ and \$ \Delta=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)} \$.

```
            ⊗θ      `[2a, 2b, 2c]`
         ⁻Σθ        Vectorised subtract from `a+b+c`
        Π           Take the product
     ∕Πθ            Divide `abc` by that
    ⊖               Decrement
   ×          Πθ    Multiply by `abc`
  ∕             Σθ  Divide by `a+b+c`
 ₂                  Take the square root
Ｉ                   Cast to string
                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 67 bytes

```python
(a,b,c)->Math.sqrt(a*b*c*(a*b*c/(b+c-a)/(a+c-b)/(a+b-c)-1)/(a+b+c))
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZVDBbsIwDL3zFVZPCXXLoFRsQ@wP4MJx2sFJMygrgbUGaZr49s5tM4lpivT88vRkP/tAV0oOxUdrK2oaWFPpv0cApWdXv5N1sOm@AMXpYioHVgVCGIj5JVYvxXkbCTRMXFrYgIdVqwgNWp28rIn3afNZs6KxGdvxUCbKxDYhPVEk1fTVJOKfDjS2WrfLrutZxkjX0Px6Kgs4Sly15br0u9c3ID1kZdewmmGG8z5SEOSL@V8hx8W9sMAnnD7cK48o716YzjKcZXPM5vm/dftEvUuuJwfq0PRoQ7AhKTCsgOIII9muQxtHzxANU7ZfDbtjerpwehYzV15xHEGU1u7sSALkCaeV8zveK61jn9pw3xDn1v4A)

Not much to say. Uses the same formula as in [*@TimPederick*'s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203540/52210), which was based on [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203493/52210), but which uses a rather similar formula as [*@Neil*'s Charcoal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203505/52210).

$$d=\sqrt{\frac{abc\left(abc\div(b+c-a)\div(a+c-b)\div(a+b-c)-1\right)}{a+b+c}}$$

Comment: Added [another level of indirection](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203550/9481)! T_T

Answer (score 1):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 87 bytes

Port of Arnauld's answer.

```
method(a,b,c,((y :=b*a*c/(z :=((b+c-a)*(c+a-b)*(a+b-c)/(x :=a+b+c))**.5)/x)*(y-z))**.5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc3BCsIwDAbgu0/RY9qm1rUdU8E38dLWgYO5DZmw9eVrDgUPlRzy5wskw5yXT0pjz643ds@vfn3OD/AYMCLAThqEF1FDoggQZFSeC4jSq0Ddy6Ai17DRlrKMnAtxbLneaLmrVMbyAwxadJwt72Fax@lQlAzbP9piV2mHF2xOFZ@RqtLGWDTWoXW/8/kL)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>76</s></sup> 72 bytes

Saved 4 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```c
#define f(a,b,c)sqrt(a*b*c*(a*b*c/(0.+b+c-a)/(a+c-b)/(a+b-c)-1)/(a+b+c))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc5LDsIgEAbgvacgGhOgAx1KsTZexQ2MtmlSG18749VFfK6szOKfTD4GSLVEMc4226YbtqzhHgKQOB2OZ@5lkCRfkXPUWchIeZFznzI8MygSyrzajISI3XBmO98NXLDLhKWzP6ZRw6fzdj1MIT1QgIVSiBXLJTO6WDgm898yOXBfaczyj3RQvaXV6MZ3VlCDwe9Sh9UoXUKqt0SNiKPSFBYKW4ItP9@1WGuD9ePGNd6o6X17iqrf3QE)

Port of [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)'s [Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203542/9481).

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 22 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/78410)

```apl
.5*⍨×/÷+/÷¯1+⊢×.÷+/-+⍨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qi2fYo7YJhv/1TLUe9a44PF3/8HZtID603lD7Udeiw9P1QHxdbaDc/zSgwke9fY@6mg@tN37UNhGoOzjIGUiGeHgG/09TMFIwVjDhSgORCqZg2lTBHEibK1gqGBoAGRYgCKQNjYwVjIxNFIxNTAE)

Yet another port of [Tim Pederick's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203540/78410).

$$
\begin{align}
d&=\sqrt{\left(\frac{abc}{(b+c-a)(a+c-b)(a+b-c)}-1\right)\frac{abc}{a+b+c}} \\
&=\sqrt{\frac{abc}{\frac{a+b+c}{\frac{abc}{(b+c-a)(a+c-b)(a+b-c)}-1}}}
\end{align}
$$

Kind of ugly, but this is precisely what the code does. Requires `⎕DIV←1`, i.e. division by 0 gives 0 (otherwise `a=b=c` case will throw an error).

#### How it works

```apl
.5*⍨×/÷+/÷¯1+⊢×.÷+/-+⍨  ⍝ Input: a 3-length vector [a b c]
                 +/-+⍨  ⍝ (a+b+c) - [2a, 2b, 2c] = [b+c-a, c+a-b, a+b-c]
             ⊢×.÷       ⍝ product([a,b,c] ÷ above)
          ¯1+           ⍝ above minus 1
    ×/÷+/÷  ⍝ product(a,b,c) ÷ (sum(a,b,c) ÷ above)
.5*⍨        ⍝ square root
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 90 bytes

```forth
: f dup 2over * * s>f fdup 3. do dup 2over - - s>f f/ rot loop 1e f- f* + + s>f f/ fsqrt ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU7LTsMwELz7K0Y9lbIxfsRNQqX@iJUDJHFBIDk4gd8P66RIwXPwaGZ3dkJM81txC/lblmcE9N8jTPwZEk6M6RoQsmQl@rgzC8ZqPiHFGZ8xjtADQoFwwiPjbobpK824cPQ8TLMADMb37gMSa4xcIyXkAcUVB74fJLokLsLAotyWMnF/1KHaaIUGWm28RsZKtbEwtoQt7yviKPwLvVLXYnt8qBfekKVyJ2lpzk54Fsn9k7Wus@yo2slWKsfTFTWkVbubdqoSvibGblpJpZTwXI24GnG1dg1RjdSqEQ/LLw)

Port of [Kevin Cruijssen's Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203542/78410). Since the inputs are positive integers, it takes the input from the data stack and returns the result through the FP stack.

A separate FP stack makes the task a bit easier, but having to work through three alternating sums explicitly is definitely a pain.

In order to copy top three elements, I used `dup 2over` which converts `a b c` into `a b c c a b`. Thankfully I didn't need exactly "3dup" because addition `+` and multiplication `*` are commutative, and alternating sums (`c - (a - b)`) are calculated for all three rotations (`abc`, `bca`, `cab`).

```forth
: f ( a b c -- f:result )
  dup 2over * * s>f fdup  ( a b c ) ( f: prod prod )
  3. do dup 2over - - s>f f/ rot loop  ( a b c ) ( f: prod prod/rots )
  1e f- f* + + s>f f/ fsqrt
;
```